# Stress history In Ansys Mechanical APDL

Tags: transient, ansys-apdl

I'm trying to get the stress history of an element, but when i define the variable with The ESOL command, ALL the The data is empty. I'm running a full transient analysis.

Any gelo would be aprecciate.

Thanks!

I tryed to set the outres, ESOL, sites, but nothing happened.